# Evaluate Data Extension text field as a number

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I have a datafeed were numeric values have been stored as text fields. Is there a ampscript function that will allow me to evaluate the text value as if it was a number?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to resolve your data and have it more strongly typed as it'll be a bit of an uphill battle trying to resolve data issues with AMPScript. There are a couple of strategies that spring to mind.

**Handle Exceptions**

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  try {
    </script>
    %%[
        SET @Number = ADD(MyTextField,25)
    ]%%
    <script runat=server>
  } catch (err) {
    </script>
    %%[
        SET @feedback = "Fix your data"
    ]%%
    <script runat=server> 
  }
</script>
```

**Pre-Process Your Data with SQL**

Marketing Cloud supports T-SQL's [ISNUMERIC function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnumeric-transact-sql). Send to a data extension with clean data.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ISNUMERIC(MyTextField) = 1
        THEN CAST(MyTextField AS INT)
        ELSE 0
    END AS MyNumberField
FROM
    SomeDataExtension
```